# How to send a generic SMS using Kannel

Tags: php, kannel

I use this Method, and it works fine

```
$url = "http://localhost:13013/cgi-bin/sendsms?username=tester&password=foobar&to=".$number."&text=Send";
$urloutput=file_get_contents($url);
```

now it doesn't work when i concatenate $text to the text parameter!

```
$url = "http://localhost:13013/cgi-bin/sendsms?username=tester&password=foobar&to=".$number."&text="." ".$text."lol'";
```

I'm not sure if this is a kannel issue or php issue ! since concatenating $number works just fine !
I'm using CakePHP 1.3 on Linux and Xampp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using **urlencode()**:

```
$url = "http://localhost:13013/cgi-bin/sendsms?username=tester&password=foobar&to=".$number."&text=".urlencode($text);
```